# What is the "gospel of the Glory of Christ" in 2 Corinthians 4:4?

Tags: word-study, historical-interpretation, pauline-epistles, 2-corinthians, grammatical-historical

What is the **gospel of the Glory of Christ** in 2 Corinthians 4:4 ?

> [2 Corinthians 4:4](https://biblehub.com/2_corinthians/4-4.htm) In their case the god of this world has blinded
>   the minds of the unbelievers, to keep them from seeing the light of
>   the **gospel of the glory of Christ**, who is the image of God.

Does it refer to something more that what is referred to as the **gospel of the kingdom of God** in

> [Mark 1:14-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark%201%3A14-15&version=ESV) Now after John was arrested, Jesus came into
>   Galilee, proclaiming the **gospel of God**, 15 and saying, “The time is
>   fulfilled, and **the kingdom of God** is at hand;[a] repent and believe in
>   the gospel.”

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Glory of Christ is the Glory of the Father as well, for this Glory pertains to both eternally, that is to say, also before the world was created (John 17:15), for time started only together with the world, being its measure, but before the world was created there is atemporality of God's glorious eternal being, which being is likewise proper both to the Father and the Son, who is the "Image and Radiance of God's Glory" (Hebrews 1:3). As the rays of the sun's glowing disc can be regarded as "image of the glowing of the sun", with an implication that the glowing disc cannot not emit its image - the rays/the radiance, to the effect that the radiance is the necessary consequence of the glowing of the disc of the sun, similarly, the Logos is the Image of the Father's Glory, to the effect that this Glory cannot but be expressed and entirely present in the Logos, with the consequence that the Logos is as necessary as the Father Himself from whom He is born, analogously as the radiance is necessarily "born" from the glowing disc of the sun.

Therefore, in the Pauline expression, the "Gospel of the Glory of Christ" indicates the divinity of Christ, for this is the eternal Glory of the Father and His co-eternal Logos, who in Jesus Christ is presented already as the Incarnate God.

Now, does it differ from Mark's expression "Kingdom of God is at hand"? In a very general sense, no, it is the same, for Kingdom of God is a name of God's - eternal King's - loving and intimate presence among His creatures, whom He grants this most intimate communication with Him through His Son. But this also means that in the Kingdom the Father and the Son communicate to the creatures that very Glory that They have even before the creatures were created by Them, the eternal divine Glory; indeed, Jesus does not grudge His and His Father's eternal Glory from humans, but even enjoins them to pursue it (John 12:23). But even without relationship with the creatures the Glory of the Father and the Son remains as it is, eternally, the "Kingdom" is a token word standing for communication of this Glory to creatures through the Incarnation of the Logos.

Comment: @Siju George I have no regard for points whatsoever. Sincerely. But have every regard and interest for theological discussion. If you find my comments wrong, please take your time and indicate to my wrongness, but if I have said true thing, then why do you down-vote me?

Comment: Down-votes come from any qualified user, not necessarily from the OP. Two different individuals have down-voted, not one. Votes are anonymous and undeclared, unless someone chooses to declare it.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili I did not down vote you. But in fact you reply was very meaningful & helpful to me both logically and spiritually as I am currently reading [The Glory of the Lord](https://amzn.to/2HzjeKt). You answer is very helpful to join the pieces to get an integrated full view of the Gospel :-) I wish there was some system to make down voters responsible for their actions. May be force them to leave a comment about their reason to down vote. It could also help the person to modify his/her answer and notify the down voter to change the decision.

Comment: @Nigel J Thanks. I just consider it a matter of decency and properness to substantiate down-voting by arguments, which will be helpful for an author of a post.

Comment: @Siju George Thanks, and sorry for thinking that you have down-voted me without giving reasons. I am glad if you find my answer meaningful and proper.

Comment: @LevanGigineishvili You are welcome. Is this glory the same as the glory mentioned in [Romans 2:7](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+2%3A7&version=ESV) ?

Comment: @SijuGeorge Yes, indeed, the "glory, honour and immortality" of Romans 2:7 are in the same semantic field. In Biblical perspective "immortality" applies only to God and that which is eternally and inseparably God's (His power, wisdom, love etc.), therefore, also the "glory" and "honour" here denote the uncreated/divine glory and uncreated/divine honour, in order that the "perishable be clothed in imperishable" (1 Cor. 15:54) and thus become also imperishable by participation, and "death be there no more" (Rev. 21:4). When we cloth ourselves in divine uncreated Glory, we dress immortality.

Comment: I am the one who downvoted your answer. I usually make it a point to comment when I do so, but we have been around this issue over and over. You mix credal ideas in with scripture as if they are both Cannon and then add your own philosophy on top of it again play scripture light. That's the last I'm going to discuss why I download your posts.

Comment: @Ruminator "Credal issues"? "play scripture light"? That's not a fair estimation. If the logic of the Scripture, sincerely and unbiasedly followed, lead one to the unavoidability of acknowledging the necessity and the co-eternity of the Logos to the Father, the fact that most of the Christian creeds (Catholic, Orthodox, Monophysite, Nestorian, sundry Protestant) acknowledge the same, does in no way diminish the soundness of this unbiased (theo)logic. Now, "my own philosophy" does not exist, there exists dialectics, neutral and unbiased, and to it I always invite you, hopefully not in vain.

Comment: @Ruminator Could you please explain what credal ideas & personal philosophies contrary to scripture exists in the answer? Since I am not an expert I need help to distinguish the difference. Thanks.

Comment: @Ruminator Brother, I think the fair behavior expected in the website is to *"Be honest. Above all, be honest. If you see misinformation, vote it down. Add comments indicating what, specifically, is wrong. Provide better answers of your own. Best of all — edit and improve the existing questions and answers!"* Please consider giving a logical explanation for your down vote. Thanks.

Comment: @SijuGeorge He is using Hebrews 1:3, which says that Jesus is the image and reflection of God's substance, not that he shares God's substance as the post presumes. So he cites addresses but preaches creeds; and philosophy. It isn't exegesis, just bad preaching.

Comment: @Ruminator Please, do not misinform first yourself, second, others. I have said nothing about substance, in the first place. And if you think that Paul here uses "substance" in the same sense as it was used in Constantinople Council of 381, then it is grossly anachronistic and unscientific, for ὑπόστασις was used synonymously with οὐσία even in Nicea in 325, and in following decades changed semantics due to treatises of Cappadocian Fathers; and you think Paul in 1st century was using the same semantics? It is a very amateurish and ahistorical attitude to this difficult field, to say the least.

Comment: Paul uses a very clear metaphor: ἀπαύγασμα τῆς δόξῆς (Hebrews 1:3) translates as "radiance of Glory [of God]", and as radiance necessarily pertains to glory (for glory radiates) so the Son is necessary for God-the Father, and so far as necessary so also co-eternal and co-divine. That's why Paul says a clause before (1:2) that Father created the universe through the Son, the "universe" means entirety of created order, thus through whom this entirety is created, the Son, is necessarily uncreated and eternal, just as Father is. Unless one wishes to blind one's own eye, it is as clear as daylight.

Comment: @Ruminator Thank you. could you please name the creed and philosophy that he is preaching?

Comment: @Levan Gigineishvihi Having read your answer I thought: The Father sent the Son-and the Son rejoices to tell us about His Father's authority to send Him. +1